# Ng-repeat and Ng-show in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to display only the first element in ng-repeat and by click display the rest elements.

That's what I tried to do without success:

```
<button data-ng-click="term = !term">Show rest</button>

    <div data-ng-repeat="y in mQues track by $index" data-ng-show="term" data-ng-init="term = $first"> 
    ...
    </div>
```

it really display only the first but the button click do noting for some reason...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your ng-show condition: `data-ng-show="term || $first"`

Comment: @user11001, try `$first` instead `$index == 1`, because indexing start from `0`

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
<div data-ng-repeat="item in items" data-ng-show="term || $index == 0">{{item.title}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div data-ng-repeat="y in mQues track by $index" data-ng-if="$first"></div>
```

I think this will help

Answer (score 0):

Using the angular [filter limitTo](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo) it is rather straight forward.

```js
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
    { title: "item 1" },
    { title: "item 2" },
    { title: "item 3" },
    { title: "item 4" }
  ]
  $scope.limit = 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<span ng-click="limit = limit == 1 ? items.length : 1">Toggle</span>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo:limit" ng-bind="item.title"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Why should I prefere the limit?

Comment: I cant use this because the ng-repeat is nested so i can't use in one controller variable

Comment: I'm not sure how nesting `ng-repeat` could impact on this solution, could you please provide more code / context?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

`ng-show` displays an element by evaluating the expression given to it.

the expression assigned to `ng-show` gets converted to `true` or `false` depending on whether the result is 'truthy' or 'falsy'. When you assign `term` a truthy value, `ng-show` is assigned true.

when you do click button, it evaluates `term = !term` and `term` then becomes `false` and therefore the whole `div` will be hidden

Answer (score 0):

Guess simpler and more straight forward:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('DisplayController', function($scope) {
  $scope.ShowRest = 0;
  $scope.items = [{
    title: 'myTitle1'
  }, {
    title: 'myTitle2'
  }, {
    title: 'myTitle3'
  }, {
    title: 'myTitle4'
  }, {
    title: 'myTitle5'
  }];
});

app.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

Then:

```
<div data-ng-controller="DisplayController">
  <div data-ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div data-ng-class="{'no-display': !$first}">{{ item.title }}</div>
  </div>
  <div data-ng-repeat="item in items" data-ng-show="ShowRest">
    <div data-ng-class="{'no-display': $first}">{{ item.title }}</div>
  </div>
  <button data- ng-click="ShowRest = !ShowRest">Show rest</button>
</div>
```

Maybe it's not the most efficient way of doing it, but it works!
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cb6pggL8/1/